# Select intersecting users

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table looking like this:

```
    ID  USER  INVENTORY [...]
    1    A     X
    2    A     Y
    3    A     Z
    4    B     X
    5    B     Y
    6    C     X
    7    C     Z
```

I would like to select all columns in rows of USERs who have both X and Y in their inventory. Like so:

```
    ID  USER  INVENTORY [...]
    1    A     X
    2    A     Y
    4    B     X
    5    B     Y
```

What would be the most efficient way of going about it? I have about 300mio records in my database, and I will need to get couple of different combinations out of it - it is not a one time job. I'm still new to SQL so please have that in mind.
I was thinking of 2 possible ways:
1) Some sort of nested select statements (but I don't know how to go about writing it and from what I've read they can be very inefficient)
2) To create a new table with a set of inventory items for each user, and intersect them to get USERs. But the problem here could be that sets can only contain up to 64 elements, and many users have more elements in inventory. 
If you have any other ideas please let me know.

Comment: Lets see your attempt at the SQL?

Comment: Try using `WHERE`. This will get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `exists` with conditional aggregation:

```
select id, user, inventory
from yourtable y
where inventory in ('X','Y') and exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable y2
  where y.user = y2.user
  group by user
  having sum(inventory = 'X') > 0 and sum(inventory = 'Y') > 0
  )
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1418f/1)

---

Or if you'd rather use a `join` instead:

```
select y.id, y.user, y.inventory
from yourtable y
  join (
      select user
      from yourtable 
      group by user
      having sum(inventory = 'X') > 0 and sum(inventory = 'Y') > 0
    ) y2 on y.user = y2.user 
where y.inventory in ('X','Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is probably to use two `exists` statements:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.inventory in ('X', 'Y') and
      exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.user = t.user and t2.inventory = 'X') and
      exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.user = t.user and t2.inventory = 'Y');
```

You want an index on `table(user, inventory)` *and* on `table(inventory)` for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select user from table where `INVENTORY` in ('X','Y') group by user having count(*)>1
```